# Mirroring p2 update sites selectively

Tags: java, maven, tycho, mirror, p2

I have a functioning Tycho build process that has multiple p2 update-sites as repositories specified. I am now required to move my build to a CI-Server that has no access to those repositories (due to proxy configurations beyond my control). The only possibility is to specify local repositories.

Mirroring all update sites is way to much for this build and takes too much time: Some of the specified repositories are quite big, for example the Eclipse Luna release update site.

I wondered if I can tell Tycho to create a "selective" mirror of all update sites, i.e. a mirror containing only the IUs that I need for the build.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a (partial) local mirror of a remote p2 repository using the [tycho mirror goal](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Additional_Tools#mirror_goal)

you can also deploy this locally mirrored repository as a zip to nexus and use the [Nexus unzip plugin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Nexus_Unzip_Plugin) to serve the p2 repo from Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

In your maven settings file you can specify the specific mirrors you want to use. I suspect your best option is to use a local nexus instance and add the dependencies your require into it. 
You should be able to do this using the mvn deploy plugin to deploy from your local maven repository built from all your p2 sites.